# How to delete seed data introduced by seed method?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project where I introduce some example data for me to test. However, when I deploy the project to the pre-production server for my client to test, he says that when he deletes the test data (introduced by the Seed method), the next time he logs into the application, it is still there. Is there a way to prevent this? 
I thought that the Seed method is only called upon successful update of the database, but it seems to be running every time the application starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the migration Seed() runs depends on your database initializer. If you are using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion then it runs every time. You could switch the deployed version to an initializer that does not run the Seed method every time such as NullDatabaseInitializer. Then when you need to apply an update you can generate a script (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script).

See here for seed info: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up commenting the Seed meethod content, as my client already has some data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little misleading, I know. The seed method will always run, so yes - your data will be recreated. What I do to avoid this, is make some simple checks in the method (e.g. if the DbSet contains any records -> do not seed).

This is not 100% percent reliable, because if all data is deleted from the pre-production table, it will still be seeded with the test data. But for my needs it has always been good enough.